# How to index subgroups in table in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Supposing I have a table like this:

```
select country_id, city_id, person_id from mytable


country_id,city_id,person_id
123,45,100334
123,45,3460456
123,45,943875
123,121,4362
123,121,124747
146,87,3457320
146,89,3495879
146,89,34703924
```

I want to index the subgroups of country_id and city_id to get such result:

```
select country_id, city_id, person_id, ???, ??? from mytable

country_id,city_id,person_id,country_num,city_num
123,45,100334,1,1
123,45,3460456,1,1
123,45,943875,1,1
123,121,4362,1,2
123,121,124747,1,2
146,87,3457320,2,1
146,89,3495879,2,2
146,89,34703924,2,2
```

In other words, I want to numerate all countries in the sequence with integer numbers from 1, and also I want to mark cities the same way within each country separately. Is there an elegant way to do it in Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f3b950de3e0eca7cba1e18372b920ad8)

Use [`dense_rank()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html):

```
SELECT
    *,
    dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY country_id),
    dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY country_id ORDER BY city_id)
FROM
    mytable
```

[Further](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-dense_rank-function/) [reading](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/)